# Python - Get random color, given a seed number as fast as possible

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, hash

I need to find a random color, given a specific seed number - fast.
given the same ID twice, should return the same color.

I did this:

```
def id_to_random_color(number):
    random_bytes = hashlib.sha1(bytes(number)).digest()
    return [int(random_bytes[-1]) / 255, int(random_bytes[-2]) / 255, int(random_bytes[-3]) / 255, 1.0]
```

The problem is that calculating the sha1 of numbers many times is very slow in total. (I'm using this function about 100k times)

Edit: The reason I use a hash function is that I want to have colors that are different for numbers that are close

e.g `id_to_random_color(7)` should be very different from `id_to_random_color(9)`

Comment: Just forget about the hash function, use the bytes directly - what good is the hash function doing if all bits are already random?

Comment: Not very helpful but for reference to anyone else looking, I compared this to just generating 3 random ints after fixing the seed value and doing that is about 30% slower than the hash method above.

Comment: You can create an `np.array` that maps an integer to a color: Every color component (e.g., R G B) can be created using `np.random.randint(256, size=large_number)` and simply accessed by the index `number`

Comment: I did get a slight improvement by just using random.random() to get a value between 0 and 1 for each of the three indices.

Comment: What's the range of `number`? BTW, you probably _don't_ want `bytes(number)`, since that returns a `bytes` string of zeroes of length `number`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using simple random number generators with kind of static variables could improve performance:

```
import random
prev, r, g, b = None, 0, 0, 0
def id_to_random_color(number):
    global prev, r, g, b
    if number != prev:
        r = random.random()
        g = random.random()
        b = random.random()
        prev = number
    return r, g, b, 1.0
```

**Update:**
As AndrewMcDowell stated in his comment, the function could return different values if the input is repeated in not sequential occasions.
Here is a possible workaround:

```
import random
memory = {}
def id_to_random_color(number, memory):
    if not number in memory:
        r = random.random()
        g = random.random()
        b = random.random()
        memory[number] = (r, g, b, 1.0)
    return memory[number]
```

**Further update:**
The same function skeleton could be used even to calculate hash:

```
memory = {}
def id_to_random_color(number):
    if not number in memory:
        numByte = str.encode(number)
        hashObj = hashlib.sha1(numByte).digest()
        r, g, b = hashObj[-1] / 255.0, hashObj[-2] / 255.0, hashObj[-3] / 255.0
        memory[number]= (r, g, b, 1.0)
        return r, g, b, 1.0
    else:
        return memory[number]
```

Despite it is a bit more verbose syntax, the `else` statement improves a bit performances, avoiding subsequent memory write and read (as Jake stated in his answer).

Comment: I did some timing and this was generally 3 times quicker on my machine than the original post but this will only give the same answer if you do the same value twice in a row. If you had number = 10, then 12, then 10 again the return values for the two calls with number = 10 would be different.

Comment: @AndrewMcDowell, yes, this simple code block can remember only one previous input. Memory could be improved using a data structure (for instance, a dictionary) and so, the issue that you mentioned could be partially solved; but if OP is looking for a strict relation between input and output values, it is not correct to talk about *random colours*.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't mention the range of `number`. It must be a non-negative integer, otherwise `bytes(number)` would fail. (BTW, that function returns a `bytes` string consisting of `number` zero bytes, which will chew up a lot of RAM if `number` is large). I presume `number` is at least 24 bits to cover the 24 bit RGB color space.

Using a cryptographic hash function for this purpose is overkill. OTOH, the `hashlib` functions are quite fast, since they're coded in C. We *could* utilize the built_in `hash` function, however `hash(n)` simply returns `n` for machine-size integers, so we'd need to do something like `hash((n, n))` to get random-looking output. However, the results of doing that sort of thing aren't particularly random: `hash` is designed for hashtable work, not for the kind of scrambling we want here.

To generate the random RGB values I've adapted the mixing algorithm from [xxHash](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash) by Yann Collet. You can view the C source code of that algorithm in the [xxhash.c source code](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash/blob/dev/xxhash.c#L278). This algorithm is reasonably fast, and it has good [avalanching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect). Bret Mulvey has written a good introductory article about [hash mixing functions and the avalanche effect](http://papa.bretmulvey.com/post/124027987928/hash-functions).

```
def id_to_random_color(n):
    n = ((n ^ n >> 15) * 2246822519) & 0xffffffff
    n = ((n ^ n >> 13) * 3266489917) & 0xffffffff
    n = (n ^ n >> 16) >> 8
    return [u / 255. for u in n.to_bytes(3, 'big')] + [1.0]
```

This function works well for `n` in `range(2**24)`, and in fact its results are quite good over the whole of `range(2**32)`; it will still give usable results outside that range. To test it here, I'll use a simplified version that returns the RGB values as integers. The first test simply shows the RGB values for `n` in `range(20)`. The second test generates 25600 random numbers and finds the corresponding RGB values. We should get approximately 100 hits for each R, G, & B value.

```
from collections import Counter
from random import seed, randrange

seed(42)

def id_to_RGB(n):
    n = ((n ^ n >> 15) * 2246822519) & 0xffffffff
    n = ((n ^ n >> 13) * 3266489917) & 0xffffffff
    n = (n ^ n >> 16) >> 8
    return tuple(n.to_bytes(3, 'big'))

# Tests

# Show some colors
for i in range(20):
    rgb = id_to_RGB(i)
    print('{:2d}: {:02x} {:02x} {:02x}'.format(i, *rgb))
print()

# Count the frequency of each color for random `n`
counts = {k: Counter() for k in 'rgb'}
for i in range(25600):
    n = randrange(2 ** 32)
    for k, v in zip('rgb', id_to_RGB(n)):
        counts[k][v] += 1

for k in 'rgb':
    print(k, sorted(counts[k].values()))
```

**output**

```
 0: 00 00 00
 1: 60 6d 18
 2: 4e f2 bf
 3: 75 4f 48
 4: 60 98 f1
 5: 17 1d 98
 6: 3b 69 13
 7: aa 10 98
 8: c1 31 e3
 9: 1e fa 4a
10: 7f 05 b2
11: 86 0e b3
12: 39 84 c6
13: c1 75 4f
14: e2 38 87
15: db 54 79
16: 45 14 b6
17: cb 56 68
18: 8e bf d8
19: cd 50 3f
```

**Counter output**

```
r [74, 75, 75, 77, 78, 80, 80, 80, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 85, 85, 86, 86, 86, 88, 88, 88, 88, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 111, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 113, 113, 113, 114, 114, 115, 115, 115, 115, 116, 116, 116, 116, 118, 119, 120, 123, 124, 126, 128, 138]
g [73, 74, 74, 77, 78, 79, 79, 81, 81, 82, 82, 83, 83, 83, 84, 84, 84, 84, 85, 85, 85, 86, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 91, 91, 91, 91, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 108, 108, 108, 109, 109, 109, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 114, 114, 114, 114, 115, 115, 116, 117, 117, 117, 117, 118, 118, 118, 119, 119, 119, 120, 120, 121, 121, 121, 123, 125, 126, 128]
b [73, 74, 77, 78, 78, 79, 80, 80, 80, 81, 82, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 87, 87, 87, 87, 88, 88, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 92, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 110, 110, 110, 111, 111, 111, 111, 112, 112, 112, 113, 113, 113, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 116, 116, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 120, 122, 124, 126, 127, 128, 131]
```

You may notice that `id_to_RGB` returns all zeroes for a zero input. If that's undesirable, you can add an extra mixing step at the start (also borrowed from xxHash).

```
def id_to_RGB(n):
    n = (374761397 + n * 3266489917) & 0xffffffff    
    n = ((n ^ n >> 15) * 2246822519) & 0xffffffff
    n = ((n ^ n >> 13) * 3266489917) & 0xffffffff
    n = (n ^ n >> 16) >> 8
    return tuple(n.to_bytes(3, 'big'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary to quickly index already generated seeds.

```
import random

random_seeds = {}

def id_to_random_color(number):
    if number in random_seeds.keys():
        return random_seeds[number]
    else:
        color = [random.random(), random.random(), random.random(), 1.0]
        random_seeds[number] = color
        return color
```